# Sql server express and connection string in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string, sql-server-express

i have connection string stored in web.config file but it is giving me the error.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DbProduct.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

where is the bug in the connection string. i have stored my db DbProduct.mdf in app_data folder. i have never use SQLEXPRESS. so i need guide line. thanks

Comment: What is "the error"? Are you intentionally using user instances?

Comment: we can set data directory this way `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"c:\users\tridip.bbakolkata\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\EFTest\EFTest");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DbProduct.mdf`

should be `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DbProduct.mdf`

You don't need to add `\`

Have a look at this [Using connection strings from web.config in ASP.NET v2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx)